# dumpbin equivalent in Qt

Tags: qt, dll, qt4, qt-creator

Is there any utility similar to dumpbin(Visual Studio) in Qt that allows me to check the functions that are exposed in a Qt-Creator compiled dll ??

I need to know what methods are exposed in a given dll so that I can load the method dynamically at runtime using QLibrary.

Thanks,
De Costo

Comment: What do you mean by "Qt-Creator compiled"? Qt-Creator is not a compiler. Presumably it's still using CL.EXE?

Comment: @Troubadour: I am using g++ wraped with mingw as the compiler. I meant the default compiler that comes with QtCreator

Comment: @de costo: QtCreator doesn't come with a compiler.

Comment: @Troubadour: I'm pretty sure he means the SDK, which includes g++, etc.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/). It is a very useful tool for any executable file, whether it's a dynamic library or an application.

Also, nothing prevents you from compiling with VC++ in Qt Creator (Qt Creator supports GCC and VC++ as compilers, maybe more) and using dumpbin, too.

Comment: Can you link to "Dependency Explorer?" I'd guess you mean Dependency Walker (depends.exe)?

Comment: VC++ refers to the IDE. the compiler is called cl.exe

Comment: @Kaleb, oh right, fixed! @shoosh, cl.exe is really a bad way to refer to Microsoft's C++ compiler that comes with Visual C++ (they have two I know of - on with Visual C++, also distributed separately, and one with the Driver Development Kit - both have the same executable but produce slightly different code).

Answer (score 2):

- On Linux and Mac, use `nm`
- On Windows, you can use `nm` via Cygwin, but I think `dumpbin` will still work. (I just tried it on a project compiled with g++ via Qt Creator, and it worked.)

Answer (score 1):

Either:

- use an existing MS Visual Studio installation and its dumpbin.exe
- install the Windows SDK (only the Win32 dev tools) and use its dumpbin.exe
- learn to use the mingw/GCC (actually binutils) `nm` and `objdump`.

I find that (even with mingw/gcc) the dumpbin.exe provides the best results.